# pandas rolling_mean of timedelta64 produces float64

Tags: python, pandas

In my code [here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/euri10/9451eb2f0fcf4cf6fe05/garmin.ipynb) (json data source [there](https://gist.github.com/euri10//9451eb2f0fcf4cf6fe05#file-output-json)) I'd like to calculate the rolling mean of timedelta objects :

```
df['rm5'] = pd.rolling_mean(df['dtd'], window=5)
```

the `df.dtypes` returns as follows, timedelta64[ns] for the dtd column and float64 for the rm5 & rm10 columns that result from the rolling_mean

```
Splits                        int64
Time                         object
Cumulative Time              object
Moving Time                  object
Distance                    float64
Elev Gain                     int64
Elev Loss                     int64
td                  timedelta64[ns]
dc                          float64
dtd                 timedelta64[ns]
rm5                         float64
rm10                        float64
dtype: object
```

Surprisingly to me the result is a float64 (column rm5 and rm10)
Some rapid googling showed me this [closed bug](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/6462)

Is that intended ? Ideally I'd like the rolling_mean result to stay a timedelta64[ns]

edit : I can still do a `df['rm5td'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['rm5'])` but I found the automatic cast wierd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be an exaggeration to say that this is intended, but it's certainly a plain result of the nature of `pandas.rolling_mean`, which will always return a float64 (it's statically encoded to at the C level).

```
>>> x
0    0.000000
1    0.333333
2    0.666667
3    1.000000
4    1.333333
5    1.666667
6    2.000000
7    2.333333
8    2.666667
9    3.000000
dtype: float32
>>> pd.rolling_mean(x, 3)
0         NaN
1         NaN
2    0.333333
3    0.666667
4    1.000000
5    1.333333
6    1.666667
7    2.000000
8    2.333333
9    2.666667
dtype: float64
>>> y
0        0j
1    (1+0j)
2    (2+0j)
3    (3+0j)
4    (4+0j)
5    (5+0j)
6    (6+0j)
7       10j
8    (8+0j)
9    (9+0j)
dtype: complex128
>>> pd.rolling_mean(y, 3)
0         NaN
1         NaN
2    1.000000
3    2.000000
4    3.000000
5    4.000000
6    5.000000
7    3.666667
8    4.666667
9    5.666667
dtype: float64
```

> I can still do a `df['rm5td'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['rm5'])` but I found the automatic cast wierd

For a mean, `pd.to_datetime` seems more applicable to me than `pd.to_timedelta`.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense, thanks for the explanation. Maybe I'm weird but I found it not very user friendly that I have to specifically 'cast' to timedelta64 an operation on timedelta64 items, then when using that timedelta64 operation result in a matplotlib graph to have again to do some formatting so that I don't AGAIN get a float :) ....

Comment: This is simply not implemented for non-float types, e.g. complex/timedelta DO need special handling. open issue is [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/11446)

Comment: thanks @Jeff I'll follow that issue, I should have looked into the repo 1st :)